# Как слово заменить картинкой посредством JS?

Tags: javascript

Условно, на странице ежеминутно появляются различные текстовые предложения. Некоторые слова мне нужно заменить картинками.
Например.

**Солнце** светило ярко, день был чудесным, я долго стоял на остановке и ждал **автобус**.

В папке img лежат картинки, каждая со своим названием.

Допустим в ней лежат две картинки:

1. Автобус.jpg
2. Солнце.jpg

Как  сделать скрипт, что бы при совпадении слов с файлами картинок в папке **img**, слова на странице заменялись этими картинками в формате `<img src="/img/Автобус.jpg" alt="Автобус">`

Разные плагины не подходят, сайт на голом php+html

Заранее  спасибо, с уважением.

Comment: проблема то собственно в чем именно? какая из частей проблему вызывает? делаете словарь доступных для замен слов. потом заменяете innerHtml для контейнера, где предложение появляется

Comment: @teran Спасибо за Ваш ответ, можете показать хотя-бы пример. Спасибо

Comment: я же не просто так спрашиваю про детали? Вы знаете список слов для замены? если да, то сформируйте массив `var repl = ["Автобус", "Солнце"]`, Если не знаете, и надо его формировать на основе файлов в папке, это другой вопрос. Как и где появляются ваши предложения? Что делать со словоформами вида "автобусА", их надо заменять, или только именительный падеж?

Comment: @teran 1)Условно список известен 2) Словоформы не появляются на тсранице, скрипт не ошибется и проверять кол-во символов не нужно в слове. 3)Алгоритм такой, текст появился, проверяются совпадения слов на странице с названиями файлов в папке img, если совпадение есть заменяется слово на картинку. Слова известны заранее, кол-во тоже.

Comment: @teran извините что не уточнил это ранее

Comment: Как Вы планируете ставить в соответствие картинки одному и тому же слову с разными падежными окончаниями?

Comment: @Igor, судя по комментарию - никак

Comment: @Arcadiy Объясню. Мне не нравится, когда так делают. Вы написали вопрос. Люди его читали, возможно - думали, писали комментарии, ответ[ы]. Вы почему-то решили - ничего мне не надо, все удаляю. А как же усилия и время, потраченные другими людьми, чтобы Вам помочь?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно так -

```js
let textfield = document.querySelector('p');
let sourceText = textfield.innerText;

let map = {
  'Солнце': 'https://emojipedia-us.s3.dualstack.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/thumbs/120/facebook/158/sun-with-face_1f31e.png',
  'автобус': 'https://emojipedia-us.s3.dualstack.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/thumbs/120/facebook/158/bus_1f68c.png'
};

const replace = (text, map) => Object.keys(map).reduce((result, key) => {
  let pattern = new RegExp(`${key}`, 'g');
  let value = map[key];
  
  let img = `<img src="${value}" />`;
  
  return result.replace( pattern, img );
}, text);

let html = replace(sourceText,map);
textfield.innerHTML = html;
```

```html
<p>Солнце светило ярко, день был чудесным, я долго стоял на остановке и ждал автобус.</p>
```

Comment: У меня будет около тысячи слов, не будет ли скрипт очень тяжелым?

Comment: @Arcadiy, здесь скорее от размера текста будет зависеть и сколько в нем будет повторов. Также можно собрать один большой regex и заменить все одним replace

Comment: `'gi'` *(9 символов нужно...)*